# Children prop in TypeScript and React 18

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

In App.tsx I'm passing `<Left />` and `<Right />` to a an imported component called `<SplitScreen />`

Apparently the "children" prop needs to be explicitly typed since React 18. If I type it as `React.Element[]` then `SplitScreen.tsx` works but `App.tsx` throws:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>'
```

If I type it as `React.ReactNode` (which seems to be the consensus currently) `App.tsx` works but `SplitScreen.tsx` throws:

```
Type 'ReactNode' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator
```

And no, `React.ReactNode[]` doesn't help, it just changes the error to:

```
Type 'ReactNode[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()'
```

```json
// package.json
{
//...
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

```
// App.tsx
const LeftHandComponent = () => {
    return <h1 style={{ backgroundColor: 'blueviolet' }}>Left</h1>;
};

function App() {
    return (
        <SplitScreen {...appProps}>
            <LeftHandComponent></LeftHandComponent>
            <!-- Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<any>' -->
            <RightHandComponent></RightHandComponent>
        </SplitScreen>
    );
}
```

```
// SplitScreen.tsx
interface SplitScreenProps {
    // extends PropsWithChildren {
    leftWeight: number;
    rightWeight: number;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    // children: React.ElementType[];
}

export const SplitScreen = ({ leftWeight, rightWeight, children }: SplitScreenProps) => {
    // Type 'ReactNode' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator
    const [Left, Right] = children; // HERE
    return (
        <Container>
            <Pane weight={leftWeight}>
                <Left></Left>
            </Pane>
            <Pane weight={rightWeight}>
                <Right></Right>
            </Pane>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

Comment: Did you try to type `children` as `ReactNode` ?

Comment: That's currently what they are typed as, thus the "Type 'ReactNode' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()'..." error

Comment: So you just need to add `[]` ?

Comment: "And no, React.ReactNode[] doesn't help" it just changes the error to "Type 'ReactNode[] | undefined' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()'"

Answer (score 1):

That is because `ReactNode` is not necessarily iterable (it can potentially be undefined, among its many other union types), so attempting to spread it into an array as: `const [Left, Right] = children`.

This can be remedied by using [`React.Children.toArray(children)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrentoarray) before attempting to spread them:

```
const [Left, Right] = React.Children.toArray(children);
```

Another suggestion is that instead of trying to treat `children` as array, perhaps a more explicit way to pass these nodes in is not to rely on `children` prop, but pass them explicitly as props, e.g.:

```
interface SplitScreenProps {
    leftWeight: number;
    rightWeight: number;
    leftNode: React.ReactNode;
    rightNode: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Then the consuming parent of the component can just do this:

```
<SplitScreen
  {...appProps}
  leftNode={<LeftHandComponent />}
  rightNode={<RightHandComponent />}>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the React.Children.toArray, it did solve that error.
Sadly it raises the old error "JSX element type 'Left' does not have any construct or call signatures" on both Left and Right
About changing the syntax, doing it as an object worked (using React.ElementType instead of ReactNode), but I'm doing a course and I needed to follow this syntax!

Comment: It also breaks as soon as I try to pass props on the App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it; [this entry](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct) had the last piece of the puzzle
The Components need to be wrapped!

```
// App.jsx

const LeftHandComponent = ({name}: {name: string}) => {
    return <h1 style={{ backgroundColor: 'blueviolet' }}>{name}</h1>
};

const appProps = {
    leftWeight: 1,
    rightWeight: 3,
};

function App() {
    return <SplitScreen {...appProps}>
        <LeftHandComponent name="Left" />
        <RightHandComponent />
    </SplitScreen>
}

// SplitScreen.tsx

interface SplitScreenProps {
    leftWeight: number;
    rightWeight: number;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const SplitScreen = ({ leftWeight, rightWeight, children }: SplitScreenProps) => {
    const [Left, Right] = React.Children.toArray(children);
    return (
        <Container>
            <Pane weight={leftWeight}>
                <React.Fragment>{Left}</React.Fragment>
            </Pane>
            <Pane weight={rightWeight}>
                <React.Fragment>{Right}</React.Fragment>
            </Pane>
        </Container>
    );
};
```